# Helm include only existing named template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using Helm for to deploy multiple K8s deployments. In some deployments I need to include extra environment variables, but for the majority of deployment the standard env. variables are enough. I would like to have named template for those deployments that must have extra env. variables.

Can I include a named template only if the named template exist?

Something like this:

```
{{ range $idx, $svc := .Values.services }}
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $svc.name }}
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ $svc.name }}
      env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
        - value: {{ $svc.javaOpts }}
# if template_exists (print $svc.name "-env")
{{ include (print $svc.name "-env") . | indent 12 }}
# end
{{- end -}}
```

It's in pseudo-code. How to do the # if part?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add additional key like `templateExists: true` to your services and check it with a simple `if` statement in your deployment:

```golang
{{- if $svc.templateExists }}
{{ include (print $svc.name "-env") . | indent 8 }}
{{- end -}}
```

```yaml
services:
  svc1:
    templateExists: true
    name: svc1
    javaOpts: "-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
  svc2:
    name: svc2
    javaOpts: "-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's no good. We have a list of services that is auto generated and there is no info if there are extra env. variables at this point. We have around 100 services and to check the list and manually add the flag is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I came up now. I check if there are any files in the chart that matches the pattern `[service]-env.yaml` and if there are then I include the content of that file in the deployment.

```
{{- range $path, $_ := $f.Glob "**-env.yaml" }}
{{- if contains $svc.app.name $path }}
{{ $f.Get $path | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

That way, for services that require extra env. variables we can include a file in `files/service-env.yaml` and those variables will be added to the deployment. For services that do not require such variables, it's left empty.